# Initializing SymmetricAlgorithm with valid values

Tags: c#, .net, security, cryptography, encryption-symmetric

I do not have a security background and the most I've dealt with cryptography is using snippets picked up from the net. After some reading up, it is clear that I need a better understanding of how these algorithms work. So please bear with any naivety.

I've tried to implement some generic/abstract methods that expect a fully initialized instance of `SymmetricAlgorithm`. As far as I can see, the transform methods are implemented fine while the calling code is not. I get exceptions as below among others:

`The input data is not a complete block.`
`Length of the data to decrypt is invalid.`

**USAGE:**

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    private static void Main (string [] args)
    {
        var cycled = "";
        Exception exception = null;
        var output = new byte [] { };
        var encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        var source = "Dude, where's my car?!";

        var algorithm = RijndaelManaged.Create();
        algorithm.GenerateIV();
        algorithm.GenerateKey();
        algorithm.Mode = CipherMode.CBC; // CipherMode.OFB;

        // I've tried multiple combinations of algorithms and modes, which all result in exceptions.

        if (SecurityUtilities.Encrypt(source, encoding, algorithm, out output, out exception))
        {
            if (SecurityUtilities.Decrypt(output, encoding, algorithm, out cycled, out exception))
            {
                var r = cycled == source;
                Console.Write("{0} = {1} == {2}.", r, source, cycled);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write(exception);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write(exception);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**GENERIC CODE:**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

public static class SecurityUtilities
{
    public static bool Encrypt (string source, Encoding encoding, SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm, out string output, out Exception exception)
    {
        var result = false;

        output = "";
        exception = null;

        if (source == null) { throw (new ArgumentNullException("source")); }
        if (encoding == null) { throw (new ArgumentNullException("encoding")); }
        if (algorithm == null) { throw (new ArgumentNullException("algorithm")); }

        try
        {
            var bytesEncrypted = new byte [] { };
            var bytesSource = encoding.GetBytes(source);

            if (SecurityUtilities.Encrypt(bytesSource, algorithm, out bytesEncrypted, out exception))
            {
                output = encoding.GetString(bytesEncrypted);

                result = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            exception = e;
        }

        return (result);
    }

    public static bool Encrypt (string source, Encoding encoding, SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm, out byte [] output, out Exception exception)
    {
        var result = false;

        output = null;
        exception = null;

        if (source == null) { throw (new ArgumentNullException("source")); }
        if (encoding == null) { throw (new ArgumentNullException("encoding")); }
        if (algorithm == null) { throw (new ArgumentNullException("algorithm")); }

        try
        {
            var bytesEncrypted = new byte [] { };
            var bytesSource = encoding.GetBytes(source);

            if (SecurityUtilities.Encrypt(bytesSource, algorithm, out bytesEncrypted, out exception))
            {
                output = bytesEncrypted;

                result = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            exception = e;
        }

        return (result);
    }

    public static bool Encrypt (byte [] source, SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm, out byte [] output, out Exception exception)
    {
        var result = false;

        output = null;
        exception = null;

        if (source == null) { throw (new ArgumentNullException("source")); }
        if (algorithm == null) { throw (new ArgumentNullException("algorithm")); }

        try
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var transform = algorithm.CreateEncryptor())
                {
                    using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cryptoStream.Write(source, 0, source.Length);
                    }
                }

                output = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }

            result = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            exception = e;
        }

        return (result);
    }

    public static bool Decrypt (string source, Encoding encoding, SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm, out string output, out Exception exception)
    {
        var result = false;

        output = "";
        exception = null;

        if (source == null) { throw (new ArgumentNullException("source")); }
        if (encoding == null) { throw (new ArgumentNullException("encoding")); }
        if (algorithm == null) { throw (new ArgumentNullException("algorithm")); }

        try
        {
            var bytesDecrypted = new byte [] { };
            var bytesSource = encoding.GetBytes(source);

            if (SecurityUtilities.Decrypt(bytesSource, algorithm, out bytesDecrypted, out exception))
            {
                output = encoding.GetString(bytesDecrypted);

                result = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            exception = e;
        }

        return (result);
    }

    public static bool Decrypt (byte [] source, Encoding encoding, SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm, out string output, out Exception exception)
    {
        var result = false;

        output = "";
        exception = null;

        if (source == null) { throw (new ArgumentNullException("source")); }
        if (encoding == null) { throw (new ArgumentNullException("encoding")); }
        if (algorithm == null) { throw (new ArgumentNullException("algorithm")); }

        try
        {
            var bytesSource = source;
            var bytesDecrypted = new byte [] { };

            if (SecurityUtilities.Decrypt(bytesSource, algorithm, out bytesDecrypted, out exception))
            {
                output = encoding.GetString(bytesDecrypted);

                result = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            exception = e;
        }

        return (result);
    }

    public static bool Decrypt (byte [] source, SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm, out byte [] output, out Exception exception)
    {
        var result = false;

        output = null;
        exception = null;

        if (source == null) { throw (new ArgumentNullException("source")); }
        if (algorithm == null) { throw (new ArgumentNullException("algorithm")); }

        try
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(source))
            {
                using (var transform = algorithm.CreateDecryptor())
                {
                    using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        cryptoStream.Read(source, 0, source.Length);
                    }
                }

                output = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }

            result = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            exception = e;
        }

        return (result);
    }
}
```

The core question is, are there mistakes in the `Encrypt/Decrypt` methods and if not, what is the bare minimum change required in the calling code to get it to work?

Comment: Your exception handling is questionable. Let them bubble up instead of returning them as a value. This pattern is especially dangerous with cryptography, but bad in general.

Comment: @usr: The `TryXXX(out exp)` pattern is what the rest of the library uses so I have no control over that. But why do you say it's particularly bad for cryprography?

Comment: Because the caller can ignore the return value by accident and proceed to execute with invalid data. If security decisions depend on that (likely with crypto code) that can be catastrophic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two errors you mention are the result of the same issue - many symmetric algorithms are "block ciphers", i.e. they work on one or more blocks of a specific size. When encrypting arbitrary length data with a block cipher, it must be padded so that its length is a multiple of the block size, similarly when decrypting, the padding must be removed to give the original, un-padded plaintext.

There are a number of different ways to pad the plaintext, and the method used is determined by the `Padding` property of the `SymmetricAlgorithm`. If this is set to `PaddingMode.None`, then the length of the plaintext *must* be a multiple of `BlockSize`.

If we assume the `SymmetricAlgorithm` instance is set to use a padding mode other than `None`, then it's necessary to tell the algorithm that you're done encrypting and it should add the padding (or when decrypting that you've read all the ciphertext and it should remove the padding). When using the `CryptoStream` this is achieved using the `FlushFinalBlock()` method, and should be performed immediately after all of the data has been written to the stream:

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var transform = algorithm.CreateEncryptor())
    {
        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            cryptoStream.Write(source, 0, source.Length);
            // Tell the CryptoStream we've written all the data and padding should be applied
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        }
    }
    output = memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

In your `Decrypt(byte[], SymmetricAlgorithm, ...)` you use `memoryStream.ToArray()` as your `output`, however `memoryStream` contains ciphertext, *not* the resulting plaintext. You should instead be able to use the same construct as for encryption, except using `transform.CreateDecryptor()` instead of `transform.CreateEncryptor()`:

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var transform = algorithm.CreateDecryptor())
    {
        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            cryptoStream.Write(source, 0, source.Length);
            // Tell the CryptoStream we've written all the data and padding should be removed
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        }
    }
    output = memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

Finally, in your `Encrypt (string, Encoding, ...)` you're taking the binary ciphertext and converting it to a string using `encoding.GetString()`, which is not valid. If you wish to represent binary data as a string, you should use something like `Convert.ToBase64String()` instead. Similarly in `Decrypt(string, Encoding, ...)`, you should use `Convert.FromBase64String()` to convert the incoming Base64 encoded ciphertext string into the byte array required for decryption.

Comment: Thank you. Does it matter which padding mode is use? Not in terms of which is `better` but just from a functional point of view.

Comment: @RaheelKhan The usual choice would be `PKCS7`. I'd avoid `Zeros` as it's potentially ambiguous if there's the possibility that your data will contain trailing zero-bytes itself.